# Android application that uses other apps

Tags: android

Is it possible to have my application use other apps for a task and get the result from them.
for example ,I want my application to preform a search in the web can i have my app send the search query to google chrome and then retrieve the search result from google chrome and use it in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
Apps publish the action they can handle.
For example, an app like Chrome will publish that it can handle web surfing and so when you click a link in one app, Andriod will offer to open it in Chrome.
That said you cannot just communicate with other apps without them first providing an API for it.
For example, the "Waze" app has integrated with "Spotify" to play music while you navigate. This was done since Spotify allows it [here](https://support.spotify.com/is/account_payment_help/privacy/revoke-access-from-3rd-party-app/).